# Merging neighbouring edges

Tags: modeling, modifiers

Is there a way to merge two neighbouring faces/polygons etc. and avoid badly stitched look of it when bevel modifier applied on it?

I'd like to create clean base without any seams on it. When I worked on a model I paid attention to receive a clean look of final object, aligned vertices and edges and finally joined all cubes and extruded vertices and faces. But when I applied Bevel modifier, every seam was visible and in some places where I extruded vertices and then made a face modifier ruined geometry of it.

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried just selecting the edges you want to bevel rather than the whole mesh?

Comment: I tried both ways and when I do only select some edges results are not satisfying as well. This is why I'd like to reduce number of objects and seams.